# Update OrderID based on the Select Order By Results?

Tags: sql, sqlite, row-number

I am using SQLite 3. I have a table MyTable, as follows:

```
    Create table mytable (ID as INTEGER, OrderID as INTEGER, a as INTGER, b as INTEGER);

    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (1, 1,1,1);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (1, 2,1,2);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (2, 1,1,3);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (2, 3,2,1);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (3, 1,2,3);
```

Now if I using the following statement:

Select * from mytable ORDER BY a desc, b desc;

I will get all rows in a different order, as follows:

```
    (3, 1, 2, 3); 
    (2, 3, 2, 1); 
    (2, 1, 1, 3); 
    (1, 2, 1, 2); 
    (1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Now I want to update the order ID to the sequence number of the rows appear in the above results, as follows:

```
    (3, 1, 2, 3); 
    (2, 2, 2, 1); 
    (2, 3, 1, 3); 
    (1, 4, 1, 2); 
    (1, 5, 1, 1);
```

How to do so?

Comment: 4,5 how come into result set

Comment: 4 means the 4th row in the result row sets, 5 means the 5th row in the result row sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
      Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1 ) ) AS ordNo, * INTO #TempTable  from 
         mytable ORDER BY a desc, b desc;
```

UPDATE   mytable  SET OrderID = ordNo FROM #TempTable WHERE mytable.ID 
             =#TempTable.ID AND mytable.a=#TempTable.a AND mytable.b=#TempTable.b

Answer (score 0):

There is a column [rowid][1] responsible for every rowid

> Most tables in a typical SQLite database schema are rowid tables.
>   Rowid tables are distinguished by the fact that they all have a unique, non-NULL, signed 64-bit integer rowid that is used as the access key for the data in the underlying B-tree storage engine.

Due to old SQLite version didn't support ROW_NUMBER window function, you can use a subquery in `select` to make it.

You can try to use correlated subquery and `UPDATE` by `rowid`.

**Schema (SQLite v3.18)**

```
 Create table mytable (ID  INT, OrderID  INT, a  INT, b  INT);

    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (1, 1,1,1);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (1, 2,1,2);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (2, 1,1,3);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (2, 3,2,1);
    Insert into mytable (ID, OrderID,a,b) values (3, 1,2,3);


update mytable 
set orderid= 
(
   SELECT (select count(*) 
              from mytable tt
             where tt.a > t1.a or
                (tt.a = t1.a and tt.b >= t1.b)) rn
    FROM mytable t1
    where mytable.rowid=t1.rowid
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable order by OrderID;

| ID  | OrderID | a   | b   |
| --- | ------- | --- | --- |
| 3   | 1       | 2   | 3   |
| 2   | 2       | 2   | 1   |
| 2   | 3       | 1   | 3   |
| 1   | 4       | 1   | 2   |
| 1   | 5       | 1   | 1   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/79y9cdLdf9Zn8eNRwso2vQ/2)

Comment: Sorry but it seems that your query does not contain a and b, which will be used to order the results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `a` and `b` values are unique:

```
update mytable t
    set orderid = (select count(*)
                   from mytable t2
                   where t2.a > t.a or
                         (t2.a = t.a and t2.b >= t.b)
                  );
```